# Java FXML - Display String length of text input field

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Folks, I want to display the string length of the input text field below the input text field. Refer the screenshot below.

Basically, I want the count to be displayed in a dynamic fashion i.e whenever a user changes the input, the count should also change accordingly.

How can this be achievable using javafx?

Also, how can the string length value be injected in the FXML file?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Bindings.length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#length-javafx.beans.value.ObservableStringValue-) returns a `IntegerBinding` containing the length of the sting value in a `StringProperty`. `asString` allows you to format the value as string:

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.length(textField.textProperty())
                                  .asString("String length: %d"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this with a binding.  Add a label below your TextField.

Create a StringBinding like this:

```
StringBinding binding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                String characterCount = "0";
                if(textField.getText() != null){
                    characterCount = textField.getText().length() + "";
                }
                return "StringLength: " + characterCount;
            }, textField.textProperty());

countLabel.textProperty().bind(binding);
```

If you want to avoid concat on each typed field, use two labels, one for StringLength: and one beside it for the character count, then only that label would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

if your label is called lbl and textField txt :

```
@FXML
void calculateLenght(KeyEvent event) {
        String text = txt.getText();
        int len = 0;
        if (text != null) {
            len = text.length();
            lbl.setText("lenght: " + len);
        }
}
```

in your fxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9"
    fx:controller="application.SampleController">
    <center>
        <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="172.0"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Label text="String" />
                <TextField fx:id="txt" onKeyTyped="#calculateLenght" />
                <Label fx:id="lbl" text="lenght:" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

please note the onKeyTyped="#calculateLenght" in TextField